# Drawing scalar field in blender

Tags: blender

I have a scalar field that I have visualised in Ensight.

Then I export it as .ply for blender.

Then I import it in blender.

I load the file, but how can I see it in Blender?

Comment: Try to ask here and more detailled your question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i'm not sure why is there the paraview tag on this.

Comment: Without a mesh surface, you would need to look at [volumetric shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/materials/special_effects/volume.html)